# Function not running after page load

Tags: javascript

I have the following function. This function works perfectly when I call it using a click event listener. However, I want it to execute after the page has finished loading.

I used to use the following to call the function after page load:

```js
window.addEventListener("load",compSummary);
```

It used to work perfectly. But I recently changed some stuff in my code, and now it doesn't work anymore. As mentioned: The function works if I use a different event listener, but not if I try to load it after the page has finished loading.
Is there anything in my code that can prevent it from working? Or should I try a different way to run the function after page load?

```js
function compSummary() {
    var e = [];
    summaryWidgetList.innerHTML = "",
    document.querySelectorAll(".component").forEach(t => {
        var o = t.querySelector(".component_name"),
            n = t.querySelector(".component_text"),
            r = t.querySelector(".component_heading"),
            m = t.querySelector(".component_product"),
            c = t.querySelector(".component_qty");
        var i = null == n ? o.textContent.trimStart() : 
            null == c ? n.textContent : m.getAttribute("data-qty") + " x " + n.textContent;
        if("None" != i) {
            var u = document.createElement("li");
            u.innerHTML = "<b>" + r.textContent + "</b>:&nbsp;" + i, 
            summaryWidgetList.appendChild(u), 
            e.push(i)
        }
    }),
    PriceField.value = document.querySelector(".comp-price").textContent,
    SummaryField.value = [...e].join("\n"),
    document.querySelector("#comp-price-display").textContent = document.querySelector(".Price-amount").textContent
}
```

***UPDATE:***

Sorry, didn't see this in the console originally. I have no idea what it means though.
The console is showing the following:
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "textContent", o is null

And it points to the following line:

```js
var i = null == n ? o.textContent.trimStart() : 
    null == c ? n.textContent : m.getAttribute("data-qty") + " x " + n.textContent;
```

Comment: "it doesn't work anymore" - from that, we cannot spot the error. You'll have to tell us more details : Do any errors show up in the console ? What makes you think that "it doesn't work" ?

Comment: Are you sure the browser is not using an old version from the cache?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff Yes, I tested it in incognito (same issue)

Comment: @Programmer please see, I just updated my question with info form the console

Comment: If `o` is null (as the error says), that means `t.querySelector(".component_name")` didn't match any elements in `t` (you might need to debug to find which iteration of the foreach loop this occurs on).